# Django dev server extremely slow

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-dev-server

We have an app that works perfectly fine on production but very slow on the dev machine.

Django==2.2.4

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 but other devs are using macOS and even Windows.

Our production server is a very small compared to the dev laptops (it works very slow on every dev environment, we are 5 developers).

The app makes several request since it's a Single Page application that uses Django Rest Framework and React.js in the front-end.

We have tried different databases locally (currently postgresql, tried MySQL and sqlite3), using docker, no docker, but it does not change the performance.

Each individual request takes a few seconds to execute, but when they go all toghether the thing gets very slow. As more request are executed, the performance starts to drop.

It takes the app between 2/3 minutes to load in the dev environment and in any production or staging environment it takes little above 10 seconds.

Also tried disabling DEBUG in the back and front-end, nothing changes.

It is my opinion that one of the causes is that the dev server is single thread and it does not process a request until the previous is finished.
This makes the dev environemnt very hard to work with.

I've seen alternatives (plugins) to make the dev server multi-thread but those solutions do not work with the latests versions of django.

What alternatives could we try to improve this?

Comment: Likely this is an N+1 problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/97197/67579 you can often fix these with `prefetch_related` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related), but it of course depends on the actual views.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like posting this question helped me think in an alternative. Using gunicorn in the dev environment really helps.

Installed it with

```
pip install gunicorn
```

And then execute it using this:

```
venv/bin/gunicorn  be-app.wsgi --access-logfile - --workers 2 --bind localhost:8000
```

Of course if I want to access the static and media files I'll have to set up a local nginx but it's not a big deal